# Update a ListView from AsyncTask spawned on a different Activity

Tags: android, callback, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have two activities an "EventsList" which extends `ListView` and a "CreateEvent" Activity.  The user can pick "Events" from the list and edit them in the CreateEvent activity.  When the user clicks save CreateEvent than spawns an AsycTask to communicate the data to a webservice, gets a response and parses the response into the database.

My problem is I dont know how to communicate the result from the AsycTasks `onPostExecute()` to the EventsList activity.  I tried refreshing the list on `StartActivityForResult` but the thread often hasn't completed itself by this point.

So, how do I communicate the result of the AsyncTask (spawned by CreateEvent) to the EventsList activity?  I had no luck trying to use a custom callback.

[image: Activity Interaction Diagram]

**Edit**

I'm really not keen on using a global flag or `adapter`.  I'm sure this is best done using a callback/Listener somehow.  That way the list is only changed or notified when absolutely necessary.

Comment: StartActivityForResult() seem to be a better way to go. A possible workaround is in your CreateEventActivity, do not immediately go back to EventsListActivity after starting AsyncTask, Instead, show user a ProgressDialog, wait for AsyncTask finish, setResult() in  CreateEventActivity, then go back to EventsListActivity, not sure if this work, but worth to try.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you fill data of `list adapter of EventsList` activity (As adapter has a global reference) in `AsyncTask` and `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask just `finish() the  CreateEvent activity` which lends you to `EventsList's onActivityResult()` now in this just call `notifydatasetChanged() for adapter`.

Comment: I could make the adapter global, but it seems a little ungraceful (I still might do it).  onActivityResult doesnt work because the AsnycTask usually hasn't finished when the CreateEvent activity is finished.  Are call backs not a better option?

Answer (score 0):

from `EventsList`  startActivityForResult "CreateEvent" .

inside async task put data as putExtra's in case large or complex dataType you want to transfer use application level data storage or static instance .

in onActivityResult of EventsList read data by putExtra or static intent .

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a `BroadcastReceiver`, and broadcast a completion action from your AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` with whatever extras you want your activity to receive.  If you need to pass an object in the result, create a model object that implements `Parcelable`, and send the `Parcelable` as an extra in your intent.